# How to fix 'flag provided but not definded: -console'

Tags: docker

I want to start a new docker container with

`docker run hello-world`

but I get the error

`...
Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: flag provided but not defined: -console
ERRO[0000] error getting events from daemon: net/http: request canceled`

What is confusing me is that is used to work the last time I tried.
The machine I am working on is not administrated by me (but I have `sudo` privileges). The admin said that he did not change anything.

Some info:

1. `docker version` -> `Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3`
2. `lsb_release -a` -> `... Description: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS ...`
3. I am connected to the server via ssh.

If I can provide any more info please let me know how to generate is.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any of your own source code to go with this question, or is this just about running a prebuilt container?  Is there a space in your directory name?

Comment: I want to run a prebuild container.
How can I check if there is space available in the directory?

Comment: I mean a space character; `/home/myname/Some Directory` could cause problems.

Comment: Stack Overflow is generally targeted towards people actually writing applications and building Docker images; the [help/on-topic] has some more information on what's good to ask here.

Comment: Do you know a better place to ask this question? Could you leave a link?
Btw: There are no spaces in my directory path.

Comment: I have just realized that the error is independent of the container that I want to use. I have updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be related to [this bug reported in Moby project](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30198) (components used by Docker).

You can try to update your Docker version to a more recent one (it seems you are using `1.13` which is quite out-of-date)

Comment: That's what I did and it did help. Though I do not understand where the error came from in the first place. Ty anyway.

Comment: Great, maybe some automated update on your system changed `runc` version (which seems to be the package causing issue in the link I provided)